# Echo multiple lines (from MySQL database) inside an HTML page

Tags: php, mysql, html, echo, lines

I'm currently using this code to print a multiple lines of text from database

```
$query_content= "select * from home ";
$result_content= mysql_query($query_content,$con);
while ($text = mysql_fetch_array($result_content))
{
    $content = $text['homecontent']; 
}
```

---

And using this HTML code:

```
<p> 
<?php print $content; ?>
<p/>
```

The text inside the database is:

```
abc
def
ghi
```

But I'm getting this

```
abc def ghi
```

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
echo str_replace(array("\r\n", "\n", "\r"), "<br>", $content);
```

Problem consists in, that in text you have a line breaks "\n", "\r" or his combinations, which in html displayed as spaces (space character).
To insert real "line break" in html, tag `<br/>` must be used.
So i wrote simple example of replacing all line breaks symbols to <br> html-tag.

In php exists special function `string nl2br ( string $string [, bool $is_xhtml = true ] )` which do almost the same, but, i think, more quickly and correctly.

Comment: In my example, the author of question will understand the principle of html, i suppose... And second... i just forgot about this function :(

Answer (score 5):

You can use the built in function [nl2br](http://php.net/nl2br) in php for this. Which converts `\n\r` (new line) to html's `<br>`.

```
<p> 
    <?php
        print nl2br( $content );
    ?>
<p/>
```

If, and hopefully, you have a xhtml or html5 compatible website you should put the second parameter to `true` to make the `<br>` xhtml compatible, `<br />`

```
<p> 
    <?php
        print nl2br( $content, true );
    ?>
<p/>
```